# SQL* Loader Handling formatted dates

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, sql-loader

I'm developing this solution where I'll receive a spool file and I need to insert it to a table.

I always use SQL* Loader and it fits well. But I never used it with dates. I'm getting this error as I'll show:

**Control File**

```
OPTIONS (ERRORS=999999999, ROWS=999999999)
    load data
     infile 'spool.csv'
     append
     into table A_CONTROL
     fields terminated by ","
     TRAILING NULLCOLS
    (
    AStatus,
    ASystem,
    ADate,
    AUser,
    )
```

**spool.csv**

```
foo,bar,2015/01/12 13:22:21,User
```

But when I run the loader I got this error

```
       Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
    ------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
    AStatus                             FIRST     *   ,       CHARACTER
    ASystem                              NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER
    ADate                                NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER
    AUser                                NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER

  Record 1: Rejected - Error on table A_CONTROL, column ADate.
  ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

  Table A_CONTROL:
    0 Rows successfully loaded.
    1 Row not loaded due to data errors.
    0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
    0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.
```

Comment: what's the datatype of `ADate` in the table?

Comment: It's "DATE" ,friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the string to date for insertion.

```
OPTIONS (ERRORS=999999999, ROWS=999999999)
    load data
     infile 'spool.csv'
     append
     into table A_CONTROL
     fields terminated by ","
     TRAILING NULLCOLS
    (
    AStatus,
    ASystem,
    ADate "TO_DATE(:ADate,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')",
    AUser,
    )
```

Comment: This works like a charm now, i was trying to use "TO_DATE" without quotes before. But now works. Thank you :)